# Advanced use of awk

Tags: awk

Say you have a file like this:

```
Rowname  
useless number  
useless number  
1596 1787  
1595 1787  
1594 1787  
1565 1803  
1565 1804
```

I know how to tell awk to skip the `useless number` and awk row 5 and 6 based on `Rowname`. BUT how can I tell awk to skip the row if the difference is only 1 from the previous row? The output should be:

```
1596 1787  
1565 1803
```

My problem is that in some cases I get this:

```
1595 1787  
1594 1787
```

Said another way: I always want the 3rd row from the row name, but I don't want row 4 (or 5 or 6) if the difference from row 3 only are 1 (or 2 or 3).

Does that make sense?

Comment: please include your existing code in your question. Good luck.

Comment: Hi! I dont have one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to meet your requirement if you want the 'Rowname' printed; if not, omit the `print` in the first line of the script:

```
$     awk '/^Rowname/         { nr=NR; print; next }
>          NR==nr+1||NR==nr+2 { next }
>          NR==nr+3           { v1=$1; print; next }
>                             { if (abs(v1-$1) > 1) print; v1=$1; }
>          function abs(x)    { return (x < 0) ? -x : x }
>         ' data
Rowname
1596 1787
1565 1803
$
```

Comment: I got it to print out the lines i wanted, but it includes the above 3 rows aswell.. I must find a way to delete those afterwards.

Comment: Rowname  
useless number  
useless number  
1596 1787    
1565 1803

Comment: You need to show exactly the output you want for the input shown, and it sounds as if there might be some other requirement not really stated in the question. If you want the useless numbers printed, you can add a `print;` to the `NR=nr+1||NR==nr+2` code (but they aren't really useless numbers if you want them printed).

Answer (score 0):

This *may* do it

```
awk '#print line 4
     NR == 4;
     #print any line that meets the "sum" comparison condition
     NR > 4 && ($1 + $2 - prev_sum != -1) && ($1 + $2 - prev_sum != 1);
     #set the sum for this line into a variable
    {prev_sum=$1 + $2}' file.txt
```

Comment: @user2966591, interesting. It works for me. In any case, I see that Jonathan's solution did the job for you. All the best.